# Modifying existing field in json column in Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

So I am trying to update some entries in my postgres database. In particular I am trying to modify a field value using the existing value. For example, say I have the following json

```
{"var1": 10, "var2": 0.003, "var3": null}
```

and I want to update var2 to var2*100. I have updated values using an update statemnt, e.g.

```
UPDATE my_table SET json_column = jsonb_set(my_column, '{var2}', '0.003', true) WHERE (my_column->'var2') is null;
```

so I am trying to use an equivalent statement

```
UPDATE my_table SET my_column = jsonb_set(json_column, '{var2}', '(json_column->'var2)::double precision*100', true) WHERE id = 12;
```

however I am facing syntax errors. Has anyone tried something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can get really tricky but you can get there with some casts. It worked for me like this:

```sql
UPDATE my_table
SET my_column = jsonb_set(json_column, '{var2}', to_jsonb((json_column->'var2')::double precision*100), true)
WHERE id = 12;
```

Comment: Yes. I knew it was something like that but I couldn't get the syntax correctly. Thank you very much